# Calling a server side function in the java script of on click event of a div ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have web page with four grid views. Each grid is hidden under a div tag. Whenever user clicks on div the data grid corresponding to the div is shown. I have binded data to the grid views at the page load only, since the data size is huge I cannot load the data binding at the page as the time taking to page load is huge. I was thinking a way that grid view gets data loaded only when user clicks on the corresponding div tag .

Kindly advice me how can we do it ?

Comment: structural problems aside, you're going to want to make an ajax call to load the data.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the first comment, you need to convert the grids to load via AJAX to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function toggle() from jQuery to display/hide the divs.

With jQuery, you can also add events when you click on a div. This event should fire the appropriate jQuery function.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/